# Finding mistakes in linear standard eulerian equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So we have:

$$
x^2y''-xy'+5y=0, x>0
$$
Wolframalpha says the answer is: $y(x) = c_1 x \sin(2 \log(x)) + c_2 x \cos(2 \log(x))$

My question is how to solve this equation using the Eulerian method?

My solution:

$$
x=e^t
$$
$$
t=\ln x
$$
$$
z=y(e^t)
$$
$$
y=z(\ln x)
$$
$$
y'=e^{-tz'}
$$
$$
y''=e^{-2t}(z''-z')
$$

Then we replace everything in the equation and we get:
$$
z''-z'+5z=0
$$
We convert the equation to:
$$
j^2-j+5=0
$$
and then the solutions are
$$1+2i$$$$1-2i$$
From here the fundamental system of solutions should be $$e^t_2 x, e^t\cos2x$$
What did I do wrong ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All seems fine, up to the point that it is
$$e^t\sin(2t),\ e^t\cos(2t).$$
You only need to replace $t=\log x$.

Comment: yeah, but still that is not the solution, which wolframalpha gives me

Comment: It is: $e^t\sin(2t)=x\sin(2\log x)$ and $e^t\cos(2t)=x\cos(2\log x)$.

Comment: oh, yeah forgot that e^lnx =x